# Guardar un array en una tabla Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola como podría guardar este request  en un tabla llamada Cat_favoritas

lo cuales el arreglo de categorías proviene de un checkbox

```html
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "mqBPCysHUomaBF52LUMisDvI4Ptx5ygYQL1MQOj3"
  "categoria" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "2"
    1 => "3"
    2 => "1"
  ]
  "user_id" => 6
]
```

Resulta que de acuerdo a los checkbox que marque el usuario los recibe el controlador

```html
   <label class="selectgroup-item">

<input type="checkbox" name="categorias[]" value="{{$categoria->id}}" class="selectgroup-input" checked>

                  
   <span class="selectgroup-button">{{$categoria->nombre}}</span>
</label>
```

pero tengo 3 tablas

```
| Users | Categorias | Cat_favoritas |
```

Primero en la vista muestra todas las categorías disponibles, ya después de haber  seleccionado solo estoy intentando guardarlo en Cat_favoritas

He estado intentando usando **SYNC** pero no se como Plasmarlo

Mis modelos y sus relaciones

|user|

```html
   public function Cat_Favorita()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cat_favorita::class);

    }
```

Modelo Categoría

```html
    public function Cat_favorita()
    {
      return $this->HasMany(Cat_favorita::class);
    }
```

Y por ultimo el modelo Cat_favorita

```html
 public function Categoria()
 {

    return $this->belongsToMany(Categoria::class,'categoria_id');
 }

 public function User()
 {
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_id');
   }
   
   No estoy seguro que esto este bie.
```

Comment: Ya intentaste recorrer las categorías con un `foreach` y hacer el insert de uno en uno

Comment: eso es lo que no quiero hacer :(

Comment: Realmente no se si eso es posible, creo que te tocará.

Comment: Revisando un proyecto antiguo encontre que si lo hice pero tu array debe tener lista toda la información para solo caer, lo hice de esta forma: `modelo::insert($array)` y si usas un `collect` lo tienes que pasar a array de la siguiente manera `$collect->toArray()` y listo me funciono sin ningún problema

Comment: @AbrahamRosales  ya  quedo. Estaban mal mis relaciones

Comment: Excelente, siempre es un gusto!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resulta que mis relaciones estaban mal:

modelo usuario quedo así.

yo tenía que un usuario tiene muchos favoritos pero no es así. En realidad  debe de quedar así mi modelo:

```html
    public function Categorias()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Categoria::class,'cat_favoritas');

    }
```

donde dice cat_favoritas. es  la tabla donde se va guardar todas mis relaciones de acuerdo a mis categorías favoritas:

Entonces el modelo categorías quedo así.

```html
   public function categorias() {

     return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'cat_favoritas');

   }
```

nuevamente. donde dice ca_favoritas. es el nombre  demi tabla donde se van a guardar todas mis relaciones.

ahora

en el controlador de esta forma  quedo

```html
auth()->user()->Categorias()->sync($request->get('categorias'));
```

Y entonces funciona!